# Encrypt value null c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I´m with a problem... How i am a newbie, i HAD this code and i am trying fix it:

```
string nomePesquisa = entryNmPesq.Text;

var nomePesqCripto = Crypto.EncryptAes(nomePesquisa, hash, salt);
string nomepesquisa = Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToBase64String(nomePesqCripto));

ApiCall apiCall = new ApiCall();

apiCall.GetResponse<List<Envolvido>>("nomes", "Envolvidos", nomepesquisa)
```

Sometimes the value of "nomepesquisa" is null and i get a error on Encripty. So, i am trying to do this:

```
if (nomePesquisa != null)
{
    var nomePesqCripto = Crypto.EncryptAes(nomePesquisa, hash, salt);
    string nomepesquisa = Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToBase64String(nomePesqCripto));
    }
else { string nomepesquisa = null; }
```

But the "nomepesquisa" is not detected because are inside of the IF and stay underlined . 
My question is: Sometimes the value will be Null and i don´t want to Encripty...in this case, i want to pass the value "nomepesquisa" on apiCall.GetResponse ! Now, because of the IF, the "nomepesquisa" is not detected.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, you want to handle the case when the value is null and you don't want to see errors?

Comment: If you get an error you should always quote the details of that error when asking a question (so exception type and message and usually a pointer to the exact line that is throwing the error).

Comment: @SayusiAndo No, is not this ! I edited my question... can you understand now ?

Comment: @Chris the error that i am having, is because the parameter "nomepesquisa" is underlined (not detecting). I am a newbie ! lol

Comment: @MarceloCFernandes: Ah, yes! And this is exactly why you need to include this in the question. I had assumed you were having a run time error rather than a compilation error. Others have given you good answers to your question though so I won't address it here. I was just trying to help advise on writing good questions.

Comment: @MarceloCFernandes Do you want to pass the value of `nomepesquisa` or `nomePesquisa`? The latter will in your case be `null` and the former will not be set, as you get an error when encrypting. Please provide the proper variable names - casing matters in C#!

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar "nomepesquisa". I would like to use like this:                     try
                    {
                        var nomePesqCripto = Crypto.EncryptAes(nomePesquisa, hash, salt);
                        string nomepesquisa = Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToBase64String(nomePesqCripto));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        string nomepesquisa = null;
                    }
But on apiCall.GetResponse<List<Envolvido>>("nomes", "Envolvidos", nomepesquisa) the "nomepesquisa" is not detected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but your `if` is in the wrong place. I presume that you want to skip the API call if the value is `null/empty`? Then this is what you should do:

```
string nomePesquisa = entryNmPesq.Text;

var nomePesqCripto = Crypto.EncryptAes(nomePesquisa, hash, salt);
string nomepesquisa = Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToBase64String(nomePesqCripto));

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nomepesquisa))
{
    ApiCall apiCall = new ApiCall();
    apiCall.GetResponse<List<Envolvido>>("nomes", "Envolvidos", nomepesquisa);
}
```

The real question is why `nomepesquisa` can be empty or `null` in the first place?

---

So what I understand from your edit: When there's input in `entryNmPesq` your want to encrypt it and send it to the API call. When there's no input, you want to send an empty string?

```
string nomePesquisa = entryNmPesq.Text;
string nomeApiCall = String.Empty;

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(nomePesquisa))
{
  var nomePesqCripto = Crypto.EncryptAes(nomePesquisa, hash, salt);
  nomeApiCall = Uri.EscapeDataString(Convert.ToBase64String(nomePesqCripto));
}

ApiCall apiCall = new ApiCall();
apiCall.GetResponse<List<Envolvido>>("nomes", "Envolvidos", nomeApiCall);
```

Comment: No, i edited the question. Check if now you can understand me please

Comment: Is it any point in encrypting nomePesqCripto if it is null? If not, the encrytion should be moved to the if block as well.

Comment: @MarceloCFernandes I can seem to grasp what you're after, but you're terribly mixing up your variable names! I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I think you got what i need!!! Thanks... i was not seeing how easy was the answer... lol
many thanks!